# C# Download PDF from URL aspx?

Tags: c#, pdf, visual-studio-2013

I tried several ways to download the PDF that is generated in this (http://187.72.229.145/esiat/Valida_NFE_Emissao.aspx?InscricaoMunicipal=0032161&NumeroNota=15&CodVrfNfe=TWU7UO47QG) ASPX page, and could not.

I try WebClient, WebRequest.. etc..
Any idea how to do this in c# e .net 3.5???

For example:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string url = "http://187.72.229.145/esiat/Valida_NFE_Emissao.aspx?InscricaoMunicipal=0032161&NumeroNota=15&CodVrfNfe=TWU7UO47QG";
        string fileName = "pdf.pdf";
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        webClient.DownloadFile(url, fileName);

    }
```

Comment: In what way did the things you tried not work. Please include the code you used, the and exception (type and message) they you got when they failed.

Answer (score 0):

You maybe need to use a proxy, add the following line :

```
webClient.Proxy = new WebProxy("192.168.1.5", 3128);  // <- Proxy address & port
webClient.DownloadFile(url, fileName);
```

And it would be better to use an absolute path for filename.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the shape of the WebClient, and it worked!

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string url = "http://187.72.229.145/esiat/Valida_NFE_Emissao.aspx?InscricaoMunicipal=0032161&NumeroNota=15&CodVrfNfe=TWU7UO47QG";
        string fileName = "pdf.pdf";
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        webClient.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(url, UriKind.Absolute), fileName);
    }
```